# Whats wrong with this proof? (trying to prove a function is surjective)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, fake-proofs

Let $f : A → B$ and $g : A' → B'$ be functions that are onto, and $h : A × A' → B × B'$
be the function $h(x, y) = (f(x), g(y))$.

Part1. Dr. Bob tries to prove that $h$ is onto with the following argument. Let
$A = B = \{1, 2\}$, $A' = B' = \{a, b\}$, $f$ be given by $f(1) = 2$ and $f(2) = 1$, and $g$ be
given by $g(a) = a$ and $g(b) = b$. Then clearly $h$ is onto, because $h(2, a) = (1, a)$,
$h(1, a) = (2, a)$, $h(2, b) = (1, b)$, and $h(1, b) = (2, b)$. What is wrong with Dr. Bob’s
proof?

I can't figure out what is wrong, bob has the outputs for $h$ as $(1,a)$, $(2,a)$, $(1,b)$, and $(2,b)$. Isn't that every element that is possible for the output? Isn't that enough to make it onto?

The second part of this problem is to correctly prove that $h$ is onto, but my proof would like bob's proof, which is incorrect.

Comment: In the statement it is implicit that it's supposed to work for all sets $A,A',B, B'$ such that $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon A'\to B'$ are functions. The proof doesn't consider this generality.

Comment: Common undergrad error...prove something by example. In this case Dr Bob should be stripped of his title :p.

Comment: Claim: All humans are male. Proof: Meet my friend Dr Bob. He is male, so all humans are male.

Answer (score 5):

What if $A, B$ are different sets than $\{1, 2\}$? What if $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $B = \mathbb{N}$?

You can't proof a general statement by specializing to a convenient case.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common error that a lot of undergrads make when they first start doing rigorous maths. The reason for it is usually due to the lack of distinction between justification and proof.

It is easy to get into the habit of thinking, "well it works for this one example so yeah its probably true" rather than, "it works in all cases so IS true".

Here is a silly example that will convince you to stop trying to prove things by example.

**Claim** - All numbers are $\pi$.

**Proof** - Hmmmm, $\pi$ is a number and $\pi$ is $\pi$...so YEAHHHHHHHH all numbers are $\pi$.

Clearly this isn't a valid proof, it hasn't proved that ALL numbers are $\pi$ since it only gives ONE possible number as an example, that happens to be $\pi$ itself.

Dr. Bob seems to make this mistake too. He has tried to prove a statement about ANY four sets and ANY two onto functions by making up one particular example.

---

EDIT: Here is a valid proof that $h$ is onto, with discussion.

What do we need to do to prove $h$ is onto? We have to show that every element of $B\times B'$ is $h$ of some element of $A\times A'$.

Ok so let's take an arbitrary element $(b,b')\in B\times B'$. Now what do we know? I know that $b = f(a)$ for some $a\in A$ (since $f$ is onto). I also know that $b' = g(a')$ for some $a'\in A'$ (since $g$ is onto).

So $h(a,a') = (f(a), g(a')) = (b,b')$. I am now done since $(a,a')\in A\times A'$ maps onto $(b,b')$, as required.

---

Do you see how the above proof would work for ANY sets and ANY onto functions? At no point did I choose a specific example!

Comment: what would be the valid way to prove h is onto?

Comment: Assuming you have learned your lesson I will add a proof in with my answer (although your question didn't ask for this).

Answer (score -1):

You need to get back to basics and definition.

Take $\forall z\in A'\times B'$, $z=(z_x,z_y)$, with $z_x\in A'$ and $z_y\in B'$.

Since $z_x\in A'$, $\exists x\in A$ such that $f(x)=z_x$ (by definition of $f$)

Similarly $\exists y\in B$ such that $g(y)=z_y$

Thus

$\forall z=(z_x,z_y)\in A' \times B'$,  $\exists (x,y)\in A \times B$ such that $h(x,y)=(f(x),g(y))=(z_x,z_y)$

Comment: This isn't answering the original question...

Comment: Well, not directly, but it is said that the second part is to correctly prove that $h$ is surjective.

Comment: But the question is asking why you can't prove by example, not how to prove the statement. In my opinion a symbolic proof by itself is just going to confuse the OP further.